# How to merge lists, preserving every one's order?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting

I have several lists, which all have their own order. The lists often share similar/equal subranges. Some lists contain an item several times.

```
B,C,D   // a list
A,B,E   // another list
A,B,A,D // a list, which contains A twice
F,G     // a list, which does not overlap with any other range
```

For to display those items, I have to merge them all together. However, the order found in each list has to be strictly kept. Short results are preferred:

```
A,B,A,C,D,E,F,G         // a valid, good result
A,B,E,A,C,D,F,G         // another valid, good result
A,B,E,F,G,C,A,D         // yet another valid result
B,C,D,A,B,E,A,B,A,D,F,G // a valid, but long (=bad) result
A,B,C,D,E,F,G           // not a valid answer, because the third input list had a B before an A
```

How can find a good, valid result list in Java?

A result list is valid, if it can be transformed into any input list, by just removing items.

Short result lists are preferred.

Comment: What is your criterion for validity?

Comment: Are you looking for [`varargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "merge"? Your original Lists have a total of 12 elements but your valid results have 8 or 12 elements. There is no easily discernable logic behind that.

Comment: Since short results are only preferred, disregard that and `.addAll` each list to get your third result?

Comment: @AndyTurner I added the validity explanation: "A result list is valid, if it can be transformed into any input list, by just removing items."

Comment: @Aaron using `.addAll` would lead to the result, that I described as "a valid, but long (=bad) result". I'm looking for a better approach than that. However adding all lists together might be an intermediate step, or a "fallback solution" for an algorithm.

Comment: Otherwise, I think I'd craft `n!` lists (each arrangement of lists), then in each of these lists try to remove each item and see if the relations described by each original list are preserved (otherwise keep the item). Once this is done with each crafted list, see which is the shortest and return it.

Comment: @Adelin `varargs` is used to allow methods with a dynamic number of parameters. That is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Aaron So, for example, adding all lists together with `.addAll` and using a backtracking algorithm to remove as many items as possible? Sounds promising!

Comment: I wouldn't call that backtracking, more like brute force, but yeah the smart alternative that would be to see whether you can reuse the items of your current list when merging another really seems bothersome. Not sure my solution would lead to optimal results in every case though.

Comment: Are you after an OrderedSet?

Comment: It sounds as though what you are looking for is simply an iterative version of this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-common-supersequence/

Comment: @crizzis Quite close, but not exactly: "AC" and "BC" should result in "ABC" or "BAC". It is important that the ordering of the entries is kept, but having other items "in between" is ok.

Comment: @Taylor I suppose, that a `Set` is not an option, because I can have duplicates.

Comment: @slartidan I still fail to see the difference. In the example solutions of the problem I've linked to, the input sequences **do** interleave within the resulting sequence (see the second example)

Comment: @crizzis You have a point with that. But it seems like the article only describes how to calculate the *length* of those results - is that correct?

Comment: So you can add 12 items together, expect 8 as the result, but need to persist duplicates?

Comment: @slartidan Yes, but it outlines the idea behind a solution: first, you find the longest common subsequence (which is a popular dynamic programming problem with plenty of solutions online, see e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem for ways to backtrack the `L` matrix that is built in the article) and then, you fill in the missing elements from both sequences, which is rather trivial

Answer (score 2):

This logic will merge the elements, with the possibility of shortening the result:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> list : listOfLists) {
  int startingPos = 0;
  for (String str : list) {
    int pos = result.subList(startingPos, result.size()).indexOf(str);
    if (pos < 0) {
      // Not found at or after startingPos. Add to the end.
      result.add(str);
      startingPos = result.size();
    } else {
      // Already in the list; just update the starting pos for next element.
      startingPos += pos + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

As to how to add them in the "best" order - no idea of a good way; but assuming the number of lists is small, you could just try every permutation and pick the shortest.

Comment: Right, `[B, C, D, A, B, E, A, D, F, G]` looks great ! ([ideone](https://ideone.com/F1wzhh))

Comment: @Aaron Except, that it does not... (too long). But thanks for the ideone - that might be helpful for other answers (or for to optimize this one).

Comment: @slartidan it's not optimal until you apply the last paragraph :) use the function with every permutation of the original lists ; I started coding that with my horrible-practice anonymous-class lists but that just got too long and I gave up.

Comment: @Aaron I spotted that. `Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")` is much easier.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, I knew there was a better solution but couldn't remind it and just rushed for the first thing that kinda worked